# Getting an array element dynamically in PHP 5?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array ($configOptions) which contains some arrays. Each array ($option) in that array has this structure:

```
array
  'manufacturer1_sender' => string 'general' (length=7)
  'manufacturer1_mail' => string 'acer@example.com' (length=16)
  'manufacturer1_template' => string       
  'orderhandling_options_manufacturer1' (length=58)
  'manufacturer1_name' => string 'Acer' (length=4)
```

The only thing that changes is the number like in **manufacturer1_name**. The number can be 2,3,4 and so on. Now I have this code:

```
foreach($configOptions as $option) {
    $name = ??????????;        
}
```

The $option is the array which I dumped above, how could I access manufacturerN_name in the foreach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways:

1 - Retrieve all the keys in the sub-array and check each one against a regular expression, capture the result into an array and then use that as the index:

```
$keys=array_keys($option); //Retrieve all keys
$name='';
foreach ($keys as $key)    //Loop
{
    if (preg_match('/^(manufacturer\d+_name)$/'),$key))
    {
        $name=$key; // We've got a match!
    }
}
```

2 - If the manufacturerN_name is always the last element in the array, use

```
$throwaway=end($option); //Retrieve last item in array
$name=key($option)       //Get index of current position
```

or some similar construct

Answer (score 0):

You get so by obtaining the number with [`sscanf`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/sscanf) from the first key (`manufacturer???_...`) and then you can format the name key with [`sprintf`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
foreach ($configOptions as $option) {
    list($refkey) = each($option);
    $number = sscanf($refkey, 'manufacturer%d_');
    if (NULL === $number) {
        throw new Exception('Could not find number in key "%s" or option %s.', $refkey, print_r($option, true));
    }
    $name = sprintf('manufacturer%d_name', $number);
}
```